# Flipping the graph in axix.bar() in matplotlib

Tags: javascript, python, sql, plot, axis

I am plotting a dataset using two y-axis values. The issue is that one side of the graph is sorted in ascending order and the other is sorted in descending order. This is causing matplotlib to begin the plot from the minimum value which is omitting it (check screenshot)
[image]

Notice how the amino-acid L doesn't have a value for percentage even though it should(which is 8.82).

```
 Percentage_dict = dict(sorted(Percentage_Map.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    Count_dict = dict(sorted(Count_Map.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
    print('Amino-Acid\tFrequency\tPercentage')
    for i in Percentage_dict:
        print(i,Count_Map[i],Percentage_Map[i],sep='\t\t')
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Amino-Acid": list(Percentage_dict.keys()),
        "Frequency": list(Count_dict.values()),
        "Percentage":list(Percentage_dict.values())
    })
    figure, axis1 = plt.subplots()
    x_axis = np.arange(len(df['Amino-Acid']))
    axis1.bar(x_axis+0.15,df['Frequency'],width=0.3,color='b',label='Frequency')
    axis1.set_xlabel('Amino-Acid')
    axis1.set_ylabel('Frequency')
    axis1.set_xticks(x_axis)
    axis1.set_xticklabels(df['Amino-Acid'])
    axis1.tick_params(axis='y',labelcolor='b')
    axis1.legend()
    axis2 = axis1.twinx()
    axis2.bar(x_axis-0.15,df['Percentage'],width=0.3,color='r',label='Percentage')
    axis2.set_ylabel('Percentage')
    axis2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='r')
    axis2.patch.set_visible(False)
    axis2.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I was asked to sort by reverse numeric order but I don't think that's the issue. I just want the y-axis to start from a value below 8.82 and make the percentage axis be sorted in ascending order. I also want the legend to appear above the graph bars

I tried using `axis.set_yslim` but it just made the graph look distorted and unreadable.

Comment: What do `Percentage_Map` and `Count_Map` look like?